# Nginx - errors on "systemctl status nginx"

Tags: nginx, systemctl

It seems that my nginx is working, when runnig "ps aux | grep nginx", I get worker and master process.

However when running the command "systemctl status nginx" I get the following output:

[image]

I don't understnad why it scans the folder usr/**sbin** after I changed it to usr/**bin** in the file nginx.service:

[image]

Any ideas how to address this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a nginx file in /etc/init.d/ ?

Comment: No, I have other files there but not nginx file